# Get text from edit text and put string into smsManager.sendTextMessage

Tags: android, android-edittext, sms

Get text from edit text and put string into smsManager.sendTextMessage. the app crashes. if i do String sms = "test" and use that for the textmessage it works fine but when i try use a string from a edit the app crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private boolean detectEnabled;
public TextView smsText;
public String smsMessage;
private ImageButton buttonToggleDetect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    smsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smsText);
    smsMessage = smsText.getText().toString();
    buttonToggleDetect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonToggleDetect);

    buttonToggleDetect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            setDetectEnabled(!detectEnabled);
        }
    });
}
```

Call Helper Class

```
public class CallHelper extends MainActivity {

public String Test = "TestString";
public Boolean calling = false;
public MainActivity mainActivity;


public CallHelper() {

}

// Listener to detect incoming calls.
public class  CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{
    @Override

    public  void onCallStateChanged (int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state){

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // case when someone is calling the users phone
                calling = true;

                Toast.makeText(ctx1,
                                "test3: " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                String phoneNumber = incomingNumber.toString();
                //EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsText);

                String  sms = mainActivity.smsMessage;
                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,null,sms,null,null);

                    Toast.makeText(ctx1,"Sms sent SuccessFully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(ctx1,"Sms Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;


        }
    }
}
```

LogCat `06-17 14:30:11.529      919-919/? E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.tmobile.driving.settingsprovider
06-17 14:30:11.649    3648-3648/westport.andrewirwin.com.drivesafe E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at westport.andrewirwin.com.drivesafe.CallHelper$CallStateListener.onCallStateChanged(CallHelper.java:46)
            at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:593)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: I posted this comment to an answer by mistake, here it is again so you're sure to see it:
Why do you have an instance of `MainActivity` when your class `CallHelper` extends `MainActivity`? What exactly is line 46 of the `CallHelper` class? Is it possible that your error is because you're trying to use an object (`mainActivity`) that hasn't been assigned yet, and really shouldn't exist?

And see the comments on mray190's answer below, your class `CallHelper` probably shouldn't extend `MainActivity` in the first place, that's almost certainly not correct.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, line 46: String  sms = mainActivity.smsMessage; i was using the an instance of MainActivity and extending it as well to access the variables. sorry this is probably completely wrong. could you give me a hand please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you read from the editText, use:

```
EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsText);
String sms = textBox.getText().getString();
```

Also, make sure you have the permissions SEND_SMS and WRITE_SMS in your Android.manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Comment: Try passing the application context in the constructor of your helper method. Then use context.findViewById instead of just findViewById. The helper method may be messing some things up since you aren't running it straight out of the extended Activity class

Comment: I know where the constructor is, but how do i pass the application context in it?

Comment: In  CallHelper: 
`private Context context;
public CallHelper(Context context) { this.context = context; }`
In MainActivity: `CallHelper callHelper = new CallHelper(getActivity());`

Comment: Why do you have an instance of `MainActivity` when your class `CallHelper` extends `MainActivity`? What exactly is line 46 of the `CallHelper` class? Is it possible that your error is because you're trying to use an object (`mainActivity`) that hasn't been assigned yet, and really shouldn't exist?

Comment: @JosephRoque good point! Never even though of that. The helper class shouldn't even extend MainActivity

Comment: @mray190 My bad, that comment was supposed to be to the original question, not you :P But I was thinking that as well. I'll repost the comment so he's sure to see it